# How is the work divided amongst Storm Workers?

Tags: apache-storm

How does Apache Storm Divide the tasks amongst it's workers, I read that storm does it by itself, and it's a function of parallelism, but what I don't know is how do I figure out which node does what and how many nodes would do which task, basically so that I can calculate the optimal number of nodes required? 
Assuming that the hardware configuration of all nodes is not the same.

Answer (score 2):

By default, Storm used "round robin" scheduling, ie, it loops over all supervisors with available slots and assigns the parallel instances of spouts/bolts. If no more free slots are available, single workers are assigned multiple spout/bolt instances.

Comment: I believe this looping happens in no particular order, so theoretically, it could happen that one particular bolt could bottleneck the system , if all it's instances end up on low end nodes, is that a correct statement? Suggested solution to this?

Comment: This is correct. You can provide a custom scheduler to Storm to control the deployment. Look here: https://xumingming.sinaapp.com/885/twitter-storm-how-to-develop-a-pluggable-scheduler/

Comment: Storm treats each worker to homogeneous thing, which means you shouldn't expect Storm that it can use whole resources properly as resource manager (YARN, Mesos, and so on). You need to take care about each node that how many workers it can run properly by opening slots, or implementing custom scheduler, as Matthias said.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a look at storm UI. The metrics: complete latency, capacity, execute latency, process latency and failed tuples will give you "hints" on how many executors and tasks you should allocate for each bolt.